# Sorting objects in Ember, Ember.SortableMixin sortProperties not working as expected

Tags: javascript, ember.js, todomvc

I'm new to Ember and recently followed the Ember "getting started" guide to build TodoMVC. Here it is in a [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/quxiyosoxu/2/edit?html,js,output).

Everything works, but now I'm trying to sort the `todos` by adding `sortProperties` to the TodosController:

```
Todos.TodosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['title'],
    sortAscending: true,
    ...
});
```

And in the template, I have this:

```
{{#each todo in arrangedContent itemController="todo"}}
  ...
{{/each}}
```

Based on the [Ember.SortableMixin documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html), what I'm doing seems to be reasonable but clearly I'm missing something.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [stevennunez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1062960/stevennunez), I understand what was missing - adding the following code fixed the problem:

```
Todos.TodosIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['title'],
    sortAscending: true
});
```

Without this controller being defined, Ember by default created a "generic" `Ember.ArrayController` which was being used to render the `todos/index` template. Thus, the `sortProperties` placed in the `TodosController` had no effect.